# gmaps4rails1.5.0-Application no longer renders map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Application fully functional yesterday [gmaps4rails 1.4.8]. New version deployed today & now application no longer rendering map. See notifications about prototype rails. And making change to config environment. But not sure how to install prototype rails. Nor knowledgeable as to what require statement is needed in config envriroment. What needs to change to revert to functional? Want to deploy this application ASAP.

Commented out config.action_view.debug_rjs=true

Errors

```
--> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js"):



--> Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates
/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
[2012-05-01 16:03:47] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software
in your host machine.
```

Comment: There is no need for prototype. You should simply run the generator to have js files copied in your app.

Comment: First want to thank you & your co-author for creating this amazing gem. Secondly, hope you're referring to this statement "rails generate gmaps4rails:install". Did not run this statement yet since 1.4.8 worked without it yesterday.

Comment: Oh... I realize I made a mistake: move the gmaps4rails js folder to public folder. Does it work now?

Comment: gmaps4rails=great gem. Core of my application's usefulness. Surprised it is free. Another question answered.

Comment: Ahah, consider points on stackoverflow as my wage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v1.5.1 just released, should fix the bug. Sorry and thanks for reporting!

Comment: Problem solved. 1: gem install gmaps4rails --version 1.5.1 [newest version]. 2: rails generate gmaps4rails:install [js files]. 3: Perfectly rendered map.

Comment: Don't know how to accept answers. Second did anything change with the geocoding? Cannot create new location.     acts_as_gmappable :lat=>'lat',:lng=>'lng'
   
    def gmaps4rails_address
      self.addr
    end                                                                                                                                      def gmaps4rails_infowindow
      "<h4>Target priority: #{tgx}</h4>" << "<h4>Address: #{addr}</h4>" << "<h4>Latitude: #{lat}</h4>" << "<h4>Longitude: #{lng}</h4>"
    end

Comment: To accept: there is a tick at the left of my question. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Reputation not high enough [11]. Can't add new location. Customized my model based on your github doc. Maybe need to add :address=>'addr'. Or another acts_as_gmappable attribute. Will experiment. Errors happen sometimes when you customize.

Comment: what error do you have? you don't need reputation to accept answers, you were trying to upvote

Comment: Oh. No error. Location is added. Shows address. But no longitude/latitude. Have lat/lng columns in model. Set acts_as_gmappable :lat=>'lat' :lng=>'lng' like in your custom model doc.

Comment: please create another question with the code from your model. And please accept my former answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Added new question --> gmaps4rails1.5.1-Geocoding not working.